# How to migrate Web API 2 to Azure Mobile App

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-mobile-services

How to migrate Web API 2 to Azure Mobile App?

I have an existing Azure website hosting both MVC4 and Web API 2. I searched and could not find instructions (step by step guide) to migrate to Azure Mobile App; what NuGet packages to add/remove and what code add/change/remove.

The best I find was migrate from Azure Mobile Service to Azure Mobile App ([this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services/) and [that](http://drew5.net/code/bits-and-bytes-migration-of-azure-mobile-services-to-azure-app-services/)).

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I did to configure an Web API 2 API controller to support Azure Mobile client.

1. Add NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server
2. Add MobileAppController attribute to ApiController class

> ```
>  //ADD THIS
>  [MobileAppController]
>  public class MobileController : ApiController
> ```

Note: To query API from browser or POSTMAN without getting error message about wrong version, set the following in web.config file

```
 <add key="MS_SkipVersionCheck" value="true"/>
```